# Instanciar Objetos Unity 5 C# Photon Networking Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, programación-funcional

Tengo un problema. Quiero instanciar 2 objetos pero al instanciar lo hace con el mismo objeto, y lo que yo quiero es instanciar el primer objeto y después de alguna forma decir que si se instanció el primer objeto se instancie el segundo en lugar de volver a instanciar el primero.

Yo intente hacerlo de esta forma:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NetworkManager : Photon.MonoBehaviour {

    public string Version;


   [SerializeField]private bool Join;

    void Start()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings(Version);
    }

    void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom("Lucha", new RoomOptions() {MaxPlayers = 2}, null);
    }

    void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        if(Join == false)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Jugador", transform.position, transform.rotation, 0);
            Join = true;
        }
        if(Join == true)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Jugador2", transform.position, transform.rotation, 0);
        }
        Debug.Log("Join");
    }
}
```

Pero no.. me instancia jugador dos veces
Lo que yo trato de hacer es que si una persona ya se conecto, que la proxima persona que se conecte en ves de instanciar jugador, se instancie jugador2

Comment: Te estas contradiciendo o no te entendi bien al decir: Quiero instanciar 2 objetos y luego ...  me instancia jugador y jugador2

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta.

Comment: Ahora lo edito.

Comment: Supuestamente el componente `networkManager` indicandole el `playerPrefav`hace esto por ti, y no haria falta que contemplaras jugador2, 3 ... ya que el código deberia de servir todo para el mismo (como si fuese local), si que es cierto que las instancias de jugador creadas por `networkManager` se identifican por un ID

Comment: Deberia... pero me sigue instanciando el mismo objeto, y yo lo que busco es que al instanciarse el primer objeto, que el segundo que se conecte instancie el segundo objeto

Comment: una duda NetworkManager es singleton ? o sea cuando ingresas el juegador 1 y 2 la instancia de NetworkManager es la misma, porque sino esta claro que el valor de variable Join se pierde

Comment: No entendi muy bien, a que te referis con que NetworkManager es singleton? estem... lo de la instancia, tengo dos prefabs diferentes para instanciar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, ya encontre la solucion... tenia que usar algo de Photon.. practicamente esto hice y funciono

```
if (PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient)
    {

        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Jugador", transform.position, transform.rotation, 0);
    }

    else
    {

        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Jugador1", transform.position, transform.rotation, 0);
    }
```

Que creo, si mal no entendi, pregunta quien es el cliente principal de la sala, y el resto habla solo, gracias por las respuestas de todos! un saludote